# Get results from where datetime has same date

Tags: mysql

How do I find results for a particular date in the following format: *2015-09-05* in a table that has datetime column in the following format *2015-09-05 13:00:39*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from your_table where date(dt_col) = '2015-09-05'
```

or to make use of indexes use

```
select * from your_table 
where dt_col >= '2015-09-05'
and dt_col < '2015-09-06'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `DATE` function. It parses string values as DATETIME and then extracts the date.